# How to get the second string in the ORA-02296 error to show something meaningful

Tags: oracle, alter-table, null

Whenever I run the following script*:

```
ALTER TABLE ANIMAL.MONKEY MODIFY TAIL_COUNT NOT NULL;
```

I receive the following error:

> ORA-02296: cannot enable (ANIMAL.) - null values found

I have a script that modifies a large number of tables.  It would be really helpful if the error message read:

> ORA-02296: cannot enable (ANIMAL.**MONKEY**) - null values found

... or something else that identifies either the problem column or the table in which it resides.

[ORA-02296](http://ora-02296.ora-code.com/) has the following detail about it:

> ORA-02296 cannot enable (string.**string**) - null values found
>
> Cause:    Obvious
>
> Action:   an alter table enable constraint failed because the table contains values that do not satisfy the constraint.

This suggests there is a second string available somehow.  How do I get the error to display more meaningful information?

**names have been changed to protect the innocent.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a name for the constraint:

```
SQL> create table monkey(tail_count number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into monkey values (null);

1 row created.

SQL> alter table monkey modify tail_count not null;
alter table monkey modify tail_count not null
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (ANIMAL.) - null values found

SQL> alter table monkey modify tail_count constraint tail_count_not_null not null;
alter table monkey modify tail_count constraint tail_count_not_null not null
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (ANIMAL.TAIL_COUNT_NOT_NULL) - null values found
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just use:

```
select * from ANIMAL.MONKEY where TAIL_COUNT is null;
```

to identify problematic rows, or add clause NOVALIDATE at the end of your alter statement.

Comment: How can it help in displaying error details ?

Comment: It can't but it may help to pinpoint problematic rows, I don't know if there any more error details to be displayed here.